# Unable to publish Powershell script to Gallery

Tags: powershell

Trying to publish a Powershell script to Gallery but getting this error:

```
Publish-Script -Path "D:\Test-AutoDetect.ps1" -NuGetApiKey $apiKey -Verbose
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'PSGallery', Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'; IsTrusted = 'False'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'PSGallery', Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'; IsTrusted = 'False'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Publish Location:'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/'.
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'PSGallery', Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'; IsTrusted = 'False'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: Using the specified source names : 'PSGallery'.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Test-AutoDetect'' for ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'0' for the specified package 'Test-AutoDetect'.
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'PSGallery', Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'; IsTrusted = 'False'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: Using the specified source names : 'PSGallery'.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/items/psscript' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/items/psscript/FindPackagesById()?id='Test-AutoDetect'' for ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'0' for the specified package 'Test-AutoDetect'.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Publish-Script" on target "Version '1.0' of script 'Test-AutoDetect'".
Publish-PSArtifactUtility : Failed to publish script 'Test-AutoDetect': 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:2875 char:17
+ ...               Publish-PSArtifactUtility -PSScriptInfo $PSScriptInfo `
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToPublishTheScript,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
```

I've added ScriptFileInfo but don't know why this happened.
I also ran `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` to force using TLS1.2 but it still doesn't work. Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you updated the powershellGet module?

Comment: Not yet, but let me have a try.

Comment: @Kiran Updated, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Once the module is updated...you would need to close and re-open the shell so that the latest version can be imported into the session. Also if it still dosent work, just remove\uninstall all old version of powershellget from your computer because it may be imported from another location.